# How do you spec a sequence/collection of values as one value to a function in clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I am trying to spec a function in such a way that it takes a sequence of two strings as the first argument to a function.

This is what I have tried:

```
(ns yoostan-lib.test
  (:require [clojure.spec :as s]
            [clojure.spec.gen :as gen]))

(s/def ::two-strings (s/cat :s1 string?
                            :s2 string?))

;; (gen/sample (s/gen ::two-strings) 3)
;; (("" "") ("7" "J") ("Tx1" "oQ"))

(s/fdef print-two-strings
        :args (s/cat :ss ::two-strings)
        :ret string?)

(defn print-two-strings
  [ss & rst]
  (with-out-str (clojure.pprint/pprint {:ss ss
                                        :rst rst})))

;; this is what I want
;; (print-two-strings '("oeu" "oeu"))
;; => "{:ss (\"oeu\" \"oeu\"), :rst nil}\n"

;; this is what I get instead
;; (s/exercise-fn `print-two-strings)
;; ([("" "") "{:ss \"\", :rst (\"\")}\n"] [("" "") "{:ss \"\", :rst (\"\")}\n"] [("90" "g") "{:ss \"90\", :rst (\"g\")}\n"]     [("IhE" "a6") "{:ss \"IhE\", :rst (\"a6\")}\n"] [("8P5" "70A") "{:ss \"8P5\", :rst (\"70A\")}\n"] [("738a" "41j4") "{:ss     \"738a\", :rst (\"41j4\")}\n"] [("M8" "4GD1") "{:ss \"M8\", :rst (\"4GD1\")}\n"] [("" "G") "{:ss \"\", :rst (\"G\")}\n"]     [("R" "8s43p") "{:ss \"R\", :rst (\"8s43p\")}\n"] [("C1e" "EY2AUE") "{:ss \"C1e\", :rst (\"EY2AUE\")}\n"])
```

To be clear. The problem I have is that `exercise-fn` interprets the `fdef` spec I gave it, as to mean that it can pass my function two arguments, both of type `string?`. What I would like instead is to get one argument, consisting of two strings passed as one collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Sequences](http://clojure.org/guides/spec#_sequences) portion of the `spec` guide:

> When regex ops are combined, they describe a single sequence. If you need to spec a nested sequential collection, you must use an explicit call to [`spec`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.spec-api.html#clojure.spec/spec) to start a new nested regex context.

So you can spec `print-two-strings` like this:

```
(s/fdef print-two-strings
  :args (s/cat :ss (s/spec ::two-strings))
  :ret string?)
```

---

Side note: I see that you're vertically aligning your arguments to `fdef`, rather than using two-space indentation as the `spec` guide does. If you're using [CIDER](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider), you can configure it to instead use two-space indentation for that macro, as documented [here](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode#indentation-of-macro-forms):

```el
(put-clojure-indent 'clojure.spec/fdef 1)
```

Or, equivalently:

```el
(define-clojure-indent
  (clojure.spec/fdef 1))
```

Here's an [example](https://github.com/samestep/env/blob/f5441afc7b56dbfd5800584da9490eff5139e75a/init.el#L50-L51) from my Emacs config.

Comment: Thank you for the tip of the indentation!

Comment: This example is wrong based on the function as defined in the question as the second argument is not optional.

Comment: Hi Alex, Sam understood the spirit of my question. The answer solved the problem or frustration that I actually had. However, I am happy to modify and/or clarify the question if you can suggest how.

Answer (score 2):

```
;; any of these will work, I'd probably use tuple here
(s/def ::two-strings (s/tuple string? string?))
(s/def ::two-strings (s/coll-of string? :count 2))
(s/def ::two-strings (s/coll-of string? :count 2 :into ())) ;; for lists in conformed value

(s/fdef print-two-strings
  :args (s/cat :ss ::two-strings :rst (s/? string?))
  :ret string?)

(pprint (s/exercise-fn `print-two-strings))

;;=> ([(["" ""] "") "{:ss [\"\" \"\"], :rst (\"\")}\n"]
 [(["H" "4"]) "{:ss [\"H\" \"4\"], :rst nil}\n"]
 [(["yZ" "7"] "OU") "{:ss [\"yZ\" \"7\"], :rst (\"OU\")}\n"]
 [(["" "FFt"]) "{:ss [\"\" \"FFt\"], :rst nil}\n"]
 [(["9" "Q0"]) "{:ss [\"9\" \"Q0\"], :rst nil}\n"]
 [(["o" "OuSA"]) "{:ss [\"o\" \"OuSA\"], :rst nil}\n"]
 [(["1JN" "bT"]) "{:ss [\"1JN\" \"bT\"], :rst nil}\n"]
 [(["IUY" ""]) "{:ss [\"IUY\" \"\"], :rst nil}\n"]
 [(["8G" "71H3r3d"]) "{:ss [\"8G\" \"71H3r3d\"], :rst nil}\n"]
 [(["qL" "zK3ZXA"] "9PV5X1")
  "{:ss [\"qL\" \"zK3ZXA\"], :rst (\"9PV5X1\")}\n"])
```

Comment: You misread the question. The `rst` parameter is only present to show that the original `fdef` doesn't work properly. Your `fdef` is not correct for a function that takes "one argument, consisting of two strings passed as one collection."

Comment: Hmm... I see what you're saying. But I still think the example you gave is wrong b/c it doesn't spec rst.

Comment: I suppose that the OP will need to clarify what he intended for the `rst` parameter. However, since his actual question was only really about the `ss` parameter, which I addressed correctly in my answer, I think that it is unfair of you to downvote my answer simply because it does not address a tangential/incidental part of the question.

Comment: I'd be happy to undo the downvote, but can't b/c it's locked. I still think the ss part is at least partly incorrect too, as you need to change `::two-strings` to get the specificed conform OP wanted  (collection of strings, not a map of string parts).

Comment: Actually, the OP didn't specify what `conform` behavior he wanted; he only showed how his original `fdef` behaves. I can certainly see how the `conform` behavior of your `fdef` could be preferable to that of mine, though.

Comment: Oh, I read the "this is what I want" to be about conform output. But that is confusing.